# get market cap from nseindia.com for given symbol list python way

Tags: python-3.x

get market cap from nseindia.com for given symbol list python way

https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=RELIANCE**strong text**
Trade Information|
Total Market Cap (₹ Lakhs): 15,77,02,517.40
Free Float Market Cap (₹ Lakhs): 7,88,53,468.88

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While getting data from nse o,h,l,c,v data is written to file,but mcap data not written